# Java array of objects, can't be convert to Type

Tags: java, arrays

Searched around but couldn't find anything that solved this problem.

We are trying to create a "memory game" that uses cards as objects and prints the array of cards into console. When trying to create an array of the cards with initial values we get the error "`MemoryGame.java:25: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Card`".

**MemoryGame:**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MemoryGame{
final int BOARD_SIZE = 4;
final int NUM_SWAPS = 1000;
private Card[][] cards;  
Random rand = new Random();

public void memoryGameBoard() {
    cards = new Card[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    initializeCards();
}

private void initializeCards() {
    int row, col;
  int cardvalue = 1;
    for (row = 0; row < (BOARD_SIZE / 2); row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < BOARD_SIZE; col++){
            cards[row][col] = cardvalue;
            cardvalue++;
        }
    }
    for (row = 2; row <= (BOARD_SIZE - 1); row++) {
        for (col = 0; col < BOARD_SIZE; col++){
            cards[row][col] = cardvalue;
            cardvalue++;
        }
    }
}

/*private void initializeCards() {
    Card[] cards = new Card[numcards];
    for (int i = 0; i <= numcards - 1; i++) {
        int a = 0;
        cards[i] = a;
        a++;
        if (a == 9) {
            a = 0;
        }
    }
}*/

public void shuffleCards() {
    int row1, col1, row2, col2;
    Card temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SWAPS; i++){
        row1 = rand.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE);
        col1 = rand.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE);
        row2 = rand.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE);
        col2 = rand.nextInt(BOARD_SIZE);

        temp = cards[row1][col1];
        cards[row1][col1] = cards[row2][col2];
        cards[row2][col2] = temp;
    }
}

public void showBoard() {
    hideBoard();
    System.out.println(this) = System.out.println(this.toString());
}

public boolean cardsMatch(int row1, int col1, int row2, int col2) {
    return cards[row1][col1].getValue() == cards[row2][col2].getValue();
}

public boolean isFaceUp(int row, int col) {
    return cards[row][col].isFaceUp();
}

public void flipCards(int row1, int col1,int row2, int col2) {
    cards[row1][col1].flipCard();
}

public String toString() {
    int col, row;
    String s = " ";
    s = s + "  1 2 3 4\n" + "=======\n";
    for (row = 1; row <= BOARD_SIZE; row++) {
        s = s + (row + "|");
        for (col = 1; col <= BOARD_SIZE; col++) {
            s = s + (cards[row][col] + " ");
        }
        s = s + "\n";
    }
}

private void hideBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private void cardsFaceDown() {

}
}
```

**and Card:**

```
public class Card {
 private int value;
 private boolean faceup = false;

public void card(int v) {
    value = v;
    faceup = false;
}

public boolean isFaceUp() {
    return faceup;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void flipCard () {
    if (faceup) {
        faceup = false;
    } else
        faceup = true;
}
}
```

The flagged line is under `initializeCards();` when trying to set a value to the cards in the array. We can't seem to get it to lay out the values. We are trying to initialize them in this layout:

```
ÏÏÏ     1 2 3 4 
ÏÏÏ    ========= 
ÏÏÏ 1 | 1 2 3 4 | 
ÏÏÏ 2 | 5 6 7 8 | 
ÏÏÏ 3 | 1 2 3 4 | 
ÏÏÏ 4 | 5 6 7 8 | 
ÏÏÏ    =========
```

The code is unfinished, currently we are trying to get our code to compile as-is.

Thanks.

Comment: Just based on the error message, what do you think the error means?

Comment: `cards[row][col] = Card.card(cardvalue);` look at that line of code and see whats wrong with it.

Comment: ...compared to this line: `cards[row][col] = cardvalue;`

Comment: Oops. That was a line that we tried, but it didn't work. Corrected with "cardvalue" which we have been using.

Comment: The line you quoted gave an error "non-static method card(int) cannot be referenced from a static context". When modified to use cardvalue, it gives the error in the OP.

Comment: your array is expecting Card objects and you're assigning an int to it.  Use the constructor to create a Card from the in value and it should work.

Comment: "Use the constructor to create a Card from the int value" This is where I get tripped up. I don't understand how to assign it to the location in the array.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find more information on constructors and figured it out thanks to some guiding from comments.

I used `cards[row][col] = new Card(cardvalue);`.

Thanks for the guiding guys!

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that you are trying to assign an `int` value to a variable that is expecting a `Card` object.

Looking at line 25 (and line 19) you have the following:

```
cards[row][col] = cardvalue;
```

`cardvalue` is of type `int` and `cards[row][col]` is expecting a `Card` object.

So you have two options:

1. Convert `cardvalue` to a Card.  E.g. in a previous edit of your question you had `cards[row][col] = Card.card(cardvalue);`
2. Change `private Card[][] cards;` to `private int[][] cards;`